# Why would Vertex AI not take the machine type while deploying endpoint for the model?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to deploy my successfully-imported on Vertex AI. But, while doing so, upon clicking "Done", the machine type is lost. And I am unable to deploy the model. Is someone else facing this too? How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you try with any `n1-standard` virtual machine?

Comment: We are also having this issue. Have you found a workaround?

Comment: Just clicked deploy when I reached the "first image" stage. As you can see the button was blue then. OR used the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue, but the command line interface works. However, I have experienced and intermittent failure with it as well.

```html
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model *args*
```